# Add to the same string variable inside a ForEach Acitivity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want a concatenated string from a Get Metadata Activity. I am passing an array of column names and data type to a ForEach Activity and I would like get a concatenated string of the column names. Is it possible with a Set Variable inside the ForEach? When I try to concatenate it is not possible to call the same variable I am concatenating to. Is there a work around?

Pipeline:

[image]

Output of Get Metadata1:

[image]

Inside ForEach:

[image]

Inside Set Variable:

[image]

I am new to Azure. Would like to know if there is a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create an dst-text variable ex. *result*
2. Create an array variable ex. *mylist*
3. Inside Foreach, add an [Append Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-append-variable-activity) with variable: *mylist* value: item()
4. After Foreach, Set Variable: *result* value: [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#join)(*mylist*,'')

Comment: Don't forget, to uncheck the sequential checkbox inside the for. ADF is super slow by default and in the sequential mode it will never finish...